# Principle of conservation of momentum

Tags: momentum, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, collision, neutrinos

when a nucleus at rest emits a beta particle, it is found that velocities of the recoiling nucleus and the beta particle are not along the same straight line. How can this be possible in view of principle of conservation of momentum?

Answer (score 4):

There is also the momentum of another particle - an anti-neutrino.

This is why the neutrino was first proposed and only discovered experimentally many years later.

Comment: Thanks a lot...